# Wicket DateTimeField dd/MM/yy Date Validation

Tags: validation, date, datepicker, wicket, date-format

I have a `DateTimeField` that I am trying to allow for 2 types of formats based on the user's preferences: `MM/dd/yy` or `dd/MM/yy`. When a user clicks `DatePicker` and selects a date, I am able to display the date in a `DateTextField` with the correct formatting. However, when I try to submit the form, I get `"'date' is not a valid Date"` alert, which is the default alert for the `DateTimeField`. Is there a way I can set, not just the pattern of the date, but the validation pattern too? I've tried implementing my own `IValidator` and `IConverter` as other posts have mentioned, but I am having no luck.

Here is the code for how I am altering the way the picked date is displayed in the `DateTextField`:

```
   DateTimeField fromDate = new DateTimeField("fromDate") { 

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override 
        protected DatePicker newDatePicker() { 
            DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(){ 

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override 
                protected String getDatePattern() { 
                     return ((String) getSession()
                            .getAttribute("dateFormat")).replace("yyyy", "yy"); 
                } 

         }; 
         return datePicker; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dateTextField with a custom converter:

```
new DateTimeField(..) {
    protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel<Date> dateFieldModel)
    {
        return new DateTextField(id, model, yourCustomConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was actually doing this as well, but did not include the property model in my new DateTextField. Stupid mistake on my part. This had me puzzled for quite some time! Much appreciated!